# Spring MVC. Request mapping not working. Links from index.jsp don't load.

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a maven project using Spring and I currently have my index page up and running on Tomcat. In my index page, I have:

```
 <a href="about">about</a>
```

Then in the WEB-INF folder I have a subfolder called jsp which includes about.jsp. I'm getting stuck on how to have that href open the about.jsp as a webpage. I tried creating a controller class, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. All I have in my controller is,

```
@Controller
public class AboutController {


 @RequestMapping("/about")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World";
        return new ModelAndView("about", "message", message); 
        }


  }
```

The servlet mapping in web.xml looks like.

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then my springMVC-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springMVC.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>


<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

I've tried a few various tutorials but they all haven't worked.

I should also note if I start up tomcat and go to localhost:8080/Test/about.jsp it works, I just can't get the linking working.

Comment: Have a look on View Resolver. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

> if I start up tomcat and go to localhost:8080/Test/about.jsp it works

It seems you have placed `about.jsp` in `web` rather than `WEB-INF/jsp`. Try moving `about.jsp` to given folder `WEB-INF/jsp`.

Answer (score -1):

you should change like this `<a href="/about">about</a>`

Answer (score -1):

You should change

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

to like this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I run your source code and the error happens like rinaldo13531 gets. Then i change view resolver such as my answer, it works fine. So that my answer is already verified